# Apache Wicket and Ajax PUSH

Tags: wicket, ajax-push

do you know some "cool" java library for Apache Wicket, which be able to do Ajax PUSH? I watched for some solution on the Wicket pages, but it looks like there is nothing :-( There is some ICE Wicket PUSH project (ICEfaces), but alpha version only... I need some simple and stable solution :-)

Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/jdk-1.5-parent/push-parent-jdk-1.5

https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/jdk-1.6-parent/push-parent-jdk-1.6

https://github.com/martin-g/wicket-atmosphere-tests